# Integrating $f(x)=1$ for $x=0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is it equal to integrating $\int x$ over the open interval $(0,1) = 1/2 - 0$?

Comment: Yes. Changing the  value of $f$ at one point does not change either integrability or the value of the integral.

Comment: You integrate on closed intervals and the integral on $[0,1]$ equals $1/2$ as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ f :(0,1) \to \Bbb R$ defiined by $f(x)=x^2$.

Let $a>0$ and $b>0$  such that
$$0<a<b<1$$
then

$$F(a,b)=\int_a^bxdx=\Bigl[\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr]_a^b=\frac 12(b^2-a^2)$$

and

$$\lim_{(a,b)\to(0^+,1^-)}F(a,b)=\frac 12(1-0)$$

thus $ \int_0^1f $ is convergent and
$$\int_0^1f=\frac 12.$$

Comment: There is no need of limits here. Also $f(x) =x$ except when $x=0$ and then $f(x) =1$.